# What is the difference between Polygon To Line and Feature To Line in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, polyline-creation, geoprocessing-framework

What is the difference between [Polygon To Line](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000003t000000) and [Feature To Line](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000039000000) in ArcGIS? Is feature to line a more abstract way such that it takes in not only polygon but like dots and other feature classes also?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a summary of the main differences. Note that both tools can split lines at intersection (it depends on the selected option):

**Input types**:

feature to lines: Lines and/or polygons

polygon to lines : polygon only

**Number of input**:

feature to lines: multiple inputs

polygon to lines : one

**Management of shared boundaries**

feature to lines: two lines* (splitted when topological relationship has changed)

polygon to lines (with neighbouring information): one line* (splitted when topological relationship has changed)

polygon to lines (without neighbouring information): two lines* (no splitting in this case)

**Management of lines intersecting the face of polygons**

feature to lines: one line*

polygon to lines (with neighbouring information): two lines* (splitted when topological relationship has changed)

polygon to lines (without neighbouring information): one line* (no splitting in this case)

**Management of attributes**

feature to lines: optionnally stores the attribute of the origin feature

polygon to lines (with neighbouring information): store the left and right FID of the original features (-1 means no neighbour)

polygon to lines (without neighbouring information): stores attributes + origin FID

*As a remark, this is valid for the most common case of two polygons sharing the same boundary or crossing each other. If there are more polygons, each relationship will result in one line. For instance, if two polygons are on the left of a third polygon and share a boundary with it, "polygon to line (with neighbour)" creates two lines.

Answer (score 1):

Polygon To Line is a tool that convert polygon feature to line feature. It is stated clearly in [Polygon To Line help](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/ArcGISDesktop/10.0/Help/index.html#//00170000003t000000) that it

> Creates a feature class containing lines that are converted from polygon boundaries with or without considering neighboring polygons.

Whereas Feature to Line not only converting polygons to lines, but also splitting line, polygon, or both features at their intersections, as stated in the [Feature To Line help](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/feature-to-line.htm)

> Creates a feature class containing lines generated by converting polygon boundaries to lines, or splitting line, polygon, or both features at their intersections

The illustrations in the above links make everything clear.